# typedef int -> integer. Can I do cout-> Print in c++?

Tags: c++

How typedef is used to define variables like int as integer or char as character. Is there any way I can do the same so i can use Print instead of cout in c++?

Comment: `cout` is not a type. Neither `int` nor `char` are functions.

Comment: `cout` is also not a function.

Comment: sorry. that was my bad. i meant variable

Comment: Well neither `int` nor `char` are variables, either. They are types. You are either quite confused or you are playing fast and loose with terminology. Neither will serve you well here: things have names for a reason.

Comment: No, however you could create your own stream class that would output everything through printf, seems counter intuitive though

Comment: `typedef` creates a new name (an alias) for an existing type. That's *all* it does. Whatever it is you're trying to do, `typedef` is not the way to do it. Please update your question to state clearly what you're trying to do (without assuming that `typedef` is the way to do it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::cout` is an object.

You can give it another name using a *reference*:

```
std::cout << "Hello ";

std::ostream& Print = std::cout;
Print << "world\n";
```

But, um, please don't. It is well understood by most what `std::cout` is and does; hiding it behind another name just introduces confusion for confusion's sake.

Comment: can I define that in a header file for my own use?

Comment: @Rohan: Sure, but it's a bad idea. There is no real benefit in being able to write `Print` rather than `std::cout` -- and it's misleading, since your `Print` doesn't actually print anything (it's the `<<` operator that does that). You'll be much better off learning how to do things in the conventional way. The problem, I think, is that you find `std::cout << ...` unclear. The solution is not to replace it with something else that you find clearer; it's to learn the standard idiom well enough that it's clear *to you*.

Comment: alright! thanks a lot. this was just meant for readability. i like my code to look all pretty :)

Comment: Prettiness is subjective and remember to think about everybody else who will read your code.

Comment: `std::cout << ...` is *perfectly* readable to anyone with any reasonable level of experience in C++ -- and `Print << ...` is not. The latter might seem clearer to someone who doesn't know C++ but that shouldn't be your target audience; such a reader probably won't be looking at your source code in the first place.

Comment: @Rohan others said it already, but just to be sure: If you change your code a lot with the sole purpose of making it more readable for you, this has mainly two effects: 1) You will not get used to c++ syntax 2) Others that are used to c++ will not find your code readable.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Generally, you have

- `using` (or `typedef`) for type aliases
- references for variable aliases
- inline functions (or macros) for function aliases

So an inline function might be a good alternative in your case (`Print` sounds like a function):

```
template<typename T>
inline void Print(T const& stuff)
{
    std::cout << stuff;
}

int main()
{
    Print("Hello");
    Print(42);
    Print("world"); 
}
```

Now you can e.g. easily change everything that used `Print` to print to `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout` by changing a single line in your code.

Comment: can I define that in a header file for my own use? This is just for readability purposes.

Comment: Yes you can. Why not? Although note that for a function definition to be in a header it needs to be marked `inline`. Otherwise the definition needs to be in a .cpp file, and only its declaration can appear in the header.

Comment: Keep in mind this method will fail if you try to pass in `std::endl`.